# Installing Python sikuli package (problems installing pyjnius) Windows 7 Python 2.6

Tags: python, sikuli, pyjnius

I am working on a Windows7 PC with Python 2.6.  I want to import sikuli into Python.  I have a problem installing pyjnius.  Here are some of the errors I have been encountering:

```
C:\Users\x\Documents\Public\pyjnius\pyjnius-master>easy_install sikuli
Searching for sikuli
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/sikuli/
Best match: sikuli 0.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/sikuli/sikuli-0.1.tar.gz#md5=c83294c6860858437572e6322ea03daf
Processing sikuli-0.1.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\x\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-dbost9\sikuli-0.1\setup.cfg
Running sikuli-0.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\x\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-dbost9\sikuli-0.1\egg-dist-tm
p-c7taex
Searching for jnius>=1.1-dev
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/jnius/
No local packages or download links found for jnius>=1.1-dev
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('jnius>=1.1-dev')
```

and then for pyjnius I get:

```
C:\Users\x\Documents\Public\pyjnius\pyjnius-master>easy_install pyjnius
Searching for pyjnius
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyjnius/
Best match: pyjnius 1.3.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyjnius/pyjnius-1.3.0.tar.gz#md5=a65f17fdc95e08f5d3de3188359f4104
Processing pyjnius-1.3.0.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\x\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-or9uvd\pyjnius-1.3.0\setup.cfg
Running pyjnius-1.3.0\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\x\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-or9uvd\pyjnius-1.3.0\egg-d
ist-tmp-kujh4w
warning: no files found matching '*COPYING'
error: Setup script exited with error: None
```

I downloaded pyjnius and run the setup:

```
C:\Users\bsprott\Documents\Public\pyjnius\pyjnius-master>python setup.py install
C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
skipping 'jnius\jnius.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'jnius' extension
error: None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not satisfy the requirements (Python 2.7). Take a look here https://github.com/kevlened/sikuli_cpython#requirements

Comment: I have the same problem but I can't understand from the requirements which one I miss.